# How do I turn off error validation for annotations in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: error-handling, annotations, intellij-idea

I have a developer counterpart who uses Eclipse, which inserts annotations in various positions automatically in our JUnit tests. However, when I open the test in IDEA, the annotation is underlined red, and the annotation reads "@Override is not allowed when implementing interface method". I don't really care about the annotation. It won't let me build because of this, and I need that validation turned off in the IDE or project settings. I've unchecked every single checkbox under Project Settings > Errors for all IDE and project settings, and it still underlines red. I don't want to have to exclude every single annotation individually under the Messages tab. Help! Thanks!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In the **Project Structure | Project** dialog, change the **Project language Level** to **6.0 - @Override in interfaces**.

Comment: Just faced same problem. My project language level already was 6.0 but @Override annotation still was highlighted. To fix that you can open *.iml file and set  LANGUAGE_LEVEL="JDK_1_6" and reload project

Comment: @GeorgyGobozov Module language level [can be changed in the module UI](http://img834.imageshack.us/img834/1958/fhan.png), you don't have to edit `.iml` files manually.