# @Override is not allowed when implementing interface method

Tags: java, extjs, intellij-idea, overriding, gxt

I have the problem mentioned in the title. You could say that this thread duplicates another one: [How do I turn off error validation for annotations in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525947/how-do-i-turn-off-error-validation-for-annotations-in-intellij-idea)

But the solution given there doesn't work. They say that I need to take the following action:

> In the Project Structure | Project dialog, change the Project language Level to 6.0 - @Override in interfaces.

However, the Project language Level is 6.0 at the moment, but I still see the error.

Vic, here is the window and there is no JVM version right under Language level (unfortunately I can't post images because I have 10 reputation)

Comment: I can't post images but there are no any options under "Project Language Level" but "project compiler output" which is not look like the JVM version

Answer (score 131, accepted):

If your project has multiple modules, also check that every module uses language level 6 or above, or use the project's language level (see `Project Settings > Modules > xxx > Language level`).

You may need to reload your project once it is modified.

Comment: yes. I have only one module, but it had the 5th language cersion. Thank you

Comment: Just faced same problem. My project language level already was 6.0 but @Override annotation still was highlighted. To fix that you can open *.iml file and set LANGUAGE_LEVEL="JDK_1_6" and reload project

Comment: For anyone else finding this that is using version 2016.2.4 or higher, the menu has changed, it's now **Project *Structure* > Modules > xxx > Language level**

Answer (score 52):

At your module/project, Right click to see context menu:
[image]

Choose `Open Module Settings` or press <kbd>F4</kbd>. In setting windows:
[image]

Set value for `Choose Language level` section.

You also should check `Project language level` by this way: press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
[image]

Answer (score 27):

**A simpler solution - inline**

1. Put the caret on the `@Override` word and move the caret on the left side until the red bulb icon will appear. Then click on it.

   [image]
2. Click on **Set language level to 6 - Override in interfaces**

   [image]

---

The method above is an **alternative** to the following approach:

1. Go to **File > Project Structure...** or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

   [image]
2. Go to **Project Settings > Modules > Sources > Language level** and choose any level that is 6 or greater than 6.

   [image]

Answer (score 15):

If you are using maven, add maven compiler plugin to the project's pom.xml file.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

There's also a language level for every module. Please check your module settings in the Project Structure.

Comment: I actually don't see any other place where I can see project language level but project-structure/project

Comment: Project Structure | Modules | <your_module> | Language Level

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem for the first time while using a multi module maven project. As other answers / IDE suggested, we need to set the language level.

Rather than changing the setting of IDE, to make the project IDE agnostic, I update the parent pom with below properties, which solved the issue.

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

In **JIdea 2020.1.2 and above**,

1. Go to **Project Structure** [ <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
   ]
2. Select **Modules** sub section
3. **Select** each **module**
4. Under sources-section, **check Language Level**
5. **Change the Language Level** as required

[image]

NOTE:

If you get below error after this change,

```
Error:java: Compilation failed: internal java compiler error
```

You have to change the target bytecode version as well.

1. Go to **Settings** [ <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
   ]
2. Select **Java Compiler**
3. Select module in the table
4. Change the byte-code version to map what you selected in the previous step for language-level

[image]