# Run all Test for one iteration of dataprovider and so on till the end of data in data provider

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-dataprovider

actually data provider have date and brand name so my first @test can only select date and brand name then in second @test it will fetch data against the same date and brand name and on second iteration first @test take second date and second brand name from @dataprovider and then second @test will do their own work and so on please help me 
thanks in advance.
example is given below :

```
`@DataProvider
  public static Object[][] dp() {
    return new Object[][] {
      new Object[] { "23", "Online" },
      new Object[] { "24", "Online" },
    };
  }
@Test(dataProvider = "dp")
  public void DateAndBrand(String date,String game) throws InterruptedException{
System.out.println(date"  "+game)
}
@Test
  public void CheckDifference(){
System.out.println("in second Test");
}
```

I want output something like :

```
23  Online 
in second Test
24  Online
in second Test
```

My testng.xml file is given below :

```
<suite name="Automation" parallel="false">
<test name="Data Difference">
<classes>
 <class name="monitoring.DataCompareAuto">
  <methods>
        <include name="DateAndBrand"/>
        <include name="CheckDifference" />
    </methods>
  </class>
</classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever we use the **dataProvider** attribute with `@Test` annotation that method is called the number of times the number of object in array returned by `@DataProvider`.

To achieve the output that you are referring, you can use the **`ITestListener`** interface or **`TestListenerAdapter`** class.

Using these listeners you can intercept each and every test method on start, success, faliure etc. You can perform any operation there.

```
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestListener;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

public class TestInterceptor implements ITestListener {
    @Override
    public void onFinish(ITestContext arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onStart(ITestContext arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult arg0) {
        System.out.println(" Can perform CheckDifference operation here.");

    }

}
```

So your output in this case will be

```
23  Online
 Can perform CheckDifference operation here.
24  Online
 Can perform CheckDifference operation here.
in second Test
 Can perform CheckDifference operation here.
```

Do remeber to add the listener in your testng.xml file

Comment: thanks it works fine but in my code when i write @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult arg0) {
        driver.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    } it is giving an exception as noelement found.

Comment: This is because of java compiler. Your project must have java compiler version older than 1.6 . Change it to a recent compiler version from Project > Build Path. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: No  java compiler version is 1.8 . its not works. i added the <listeners> tag just above to <test> tag . is it correct way to put  <listeners> right? and please help if other way

Comment: Please check the following link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15402615/override-is-not-allowed-when-implementing-interface-method